# The key 'cas/fig/h' is unknown and is being ignored

Tags: graphics, floats, positioning, els-cas

I need to put a figure in a specific position in my text, and I tried `{h}`, `{ht}`, `{hbt}` in my commands, but I get this error:

> LaTeX error: "kernel/key-unknown" The key 'cas/fig/h' is unknown and is being ignored. For immediate help type H .

This is my code for plotting my figure:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=.5]{flowchart.pdf}
    \caption{The schematic workflow of the rock-frame calibration.}
    \label{fig1}
\end{figure}
```

I used the following packages:

```
\usepackage{lineno}
 \usepackage{float}
  \usepackage{here}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

Could you please help me to solve the problem?

Comment: The most important piece of information is missing: what document class are you using?

Comment: Thanks for comment, my document class is:

\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn]{cas-sc}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `cas-sc` class redefines `figure` and the optional argument accepts a key-value type of syntax.

```latex
\documentclass{cas-sc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{natbib}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for context

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}[pos=htp]
\centering

\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image}

\caption{Test of figure}

\end{figure}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]